# Is it possible to create scroll in generic transition Stylus mixin?

Tags: css, transition, stylus

JavaScript:

```
const show = entries => entries[0].isIntersecting ? entries[0].classList.remove('is-hidden') : null;
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(show, {threshold:0});
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-hidden')).forEach(element => observer.observe(element));
```

I want to play fade in animation when '.js-hidden' class are removed like below... but this code are not working:

HTML:

```
<div class="my-component js-hidden is-hidden">
    <p class="text text-1">Hello</p>
    <p class="text text-2">World</p>
</div>
```

Stylus:

```
fadeIn(duration=1s, delay=0s) {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity duration ease delay;
    &.is-hidden { // <- yeah, this is wrong... but, any ideas? I want to apply transition both element and pseudo element.
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.my-component {
    .text,
    &::before,
    &::after {
        fadeIn();
    }
    .text-2 {
        transition-delay: .3s;
    }
    &::before {
        content: 'foo';
        transition-delay: .5s;
    }
    &::after {
        content: 'bar';
        transition-delay: .7s;
    }
}
```

And, if the fade in elements are more nested?

```
<div class="my-component js-hidden is-hidden">
    <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div class="wrapper-2">
            <p class="text text-1">Hello</p>
            <p class="text text-2">World</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply transition both element and pseudo element. but I don’t know what should I do...

Thanks.

---

**Finally...**

Thank you Andy.

Finally I arrived the code below. XD

JavaScript:

```
const show = entries => entries[0].isIntersecting ? entries[0].target.classList.remove('is-hidden') : null;
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(show, {threshold:0});
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-hidden')).forEach(element => observer.observe(element));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="my-component js-hidden is-hidden">
  <p class="text text-1">Hello</p>
  <p class="text text-2">World</p>
  <p class="text text-3">Hello</p>
  <p class="text text-4">World</p>
  <p class="text text-5">Hello</p>
  <p class="text text-6">World</p>
  <p class="text text-7">Hello</p>
  <p class="text text-8">World</p>
  <p class="text text-9">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Stylus:

```
fadeIn(target, duration=1s, delay=0s, property=all, easing=ease) {
    {target} {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: duration property easing delay;
    }
    &.is-hidden {
        {target} {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
}

.my-component {
    duration = .3s;
    delay = 1s;
    fadeIn('.text', duration:duration, delay:delay);
    fadeIn('&::before', duration:duration, delay:delay);
    fadeIn('&::after', duration:duration, delay:delay);

    interval = duration;
    amount = 9;
    for i in 2..amount {
        .text-{i} {
            transition-delay: (interval * (i - 2) + duration + delay)s;
        }
    }

    &::before {
        content: 'FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO';
        transition-delay: (interval * ((amount + 1) - 2) + duration + delay)s;
    }
    &::after {
        content: 'BARRRRRRRRRRRRRR';
        transition-delay: (interval * ((amount + 2) - 2) + duration + delay)s;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `IntersectionObserver`?

Comment: @YazanWYusuf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Ah, okay. I learned a little `Stylus` today. That looks pretty clean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it seems you're looking for a `transition`, not an `animation`. I'm not a `Stylus` expert, but know `IntersectionObserver` and `CSS` pretty well. I have the basic demo working now.

Some notes on the adjusted `fadeIn` function.

- `is-hidden` is a class that exists in the DOM from the beginning, so cue the `transition` when it's *not* there
- use a delegate pattern from transitions—that is, have the change in the parent affect the children (don't listen for a class for each child/pseudo element)

```
fadeIn(duration=1s, delay=0s) {
  .text,
  &::before,
  &::after {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease;
  }

  &:not(.is-hidden) {
    .text,
    &::before,
    &::after {
      opacity: 1;
    }    
  }  
}
```

Also, I couldn't get your `JavaScript` to work due to some errors and rewrote it to suit the demo. Here's the rewritten `JavaScript`:

```
const components = document.querySelectorAll(".my-component");

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(components => {
  components.forEach(component => {
    if (component.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      component.target.classList.remove("is-hidden")
    } else {
      component.target.classList.add("is-hidden")
    }
  })
});

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".js-hidden")).forEach(element =>
  observer.observe(element)
);
```

[image]

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/antibland/pen/PVMNeb)

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer Andy!
I'll rename this question confusing title and JS typo soon... and finally I arrived the thing. many many thanks.